# Passing run arguments in a java program from command line gives an error

Tags: java, regex, batch-file, command-prompt

I have a simple java program which takes run arguments of length three , these are my arguments

```
www\u_business_service.do namegt(test|dev)*.server-net.com  localhost.server-net.com
```

Although the program and the run-arguments run fine when I run it on eclipse, but when I try to do the same form the command prompt running it as

```
java ReplaceText u_business_application.do namegt(test|dev)*.server-net.com  localhost.server-net.com
```

it gives me an error as :

```
'dev)*.service-now.com' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

I assume it doesn't like the * or some other character, but is there a way around this?

Thanks

Comment: Try placing your arguments into quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'|' character (one that you between test and dev) is a pipe character, that tells you OS to start new program and pass output of first to input of second. Just embed your arguments into quotes.

```
java ReplaceText "u_business_application.do namegt(test|dev)*.server-net.com  localhost.server-net.com"
```

Comment: I am running on windows, and when you say embedded the argument you mean like this 

java ReplaceText "u_business_application.do namegt(test|dev)*.server-net.com  localhost.server-net.com"   ?